# In Java Script, when I click a button to make a popup modal appear, it only stays loaded for a second and then goes away

Tags: javascript, popup, simplemodal

When I click on a button to load a popup modal, the popup appears for a millisecond (you can just about see it and then it goes away again).

Does anyone know why this may be?

Below is the Java Script code I am using. As I mentioned the popup does load and then it goes away straight away.

Above this Java Script I do have another modal popup that does work and stays loaded once I click the button, but I am not sure how why the below will not work.

```
        var contactModal = document.getElementById("contactModal");


        var contactBtn = document.getElementById("Contact");


        var span = document.getElementsByClassName("contactModalClose")[0];


        contactBtn.onclick = function() {
          contactModal.style.display = "block";
        }


        span.onclick = function() {
          modal.style.display = "none";
        }


        window.onclick = function(event) {
          if (event.target == modal) {
            contactModal.style.display = "none";
          }
        }
```

Comment: Can you share the code snippet

Comment: The contact button wouldn't happen to be a submit button in a form, would it?

Comment: Why do you have that hiding code in ` window.onclick`?

Comment: @Taplar - Yes the contact button is also the submit button for the form. As I mentioned previously, it does seem to load, but only for a split second and then it goes away. Is this a common issue in JS. I feel like there is something very simple and easy that I am doing wrong

Comment: @Viney it is set up this was so that if the user clicks anywhere outside the modal content the modal turns to display none and the user is back at the home page

Comment: If you are submitting a form, then the page is going to reload.  Anything dynamically created on the old page, such as a modal, will be lost when the page transfers.

Comment: hey - I am pretty new here and not sure if this is the done thing, but I figured it out. I think the issue was that in my JS I using get.ElementById.onclick - however in my code I had both an ID and a Class associated to the element that I had the onclick function associated with. Do you guys think this makes sense. And thank you for all your help